# Share List between subsites of sharepoint2010

Tags: splist, spsite

Anyone know how can we share one subsites list to another subsite ? I want to allow all operations also and also want to put in read only mode in another subsite. Anyone have idea how can i do this ?

Answer (score 3):

A SharePoint list lives in one site and one site only.

But depending on your needs the content of the list can be displayed in other sites invarious ways.

- Content Query Web part
- [Share a List View Between Sites in SharePoint 2010](http://chayadigital.wordpress.com/2011/04/22/share-a-list-view-between-sites-in-sharepoint-2010/)
- [implementing a simple Cross SIte collection list view webpart](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ramg/archive/2009/04/22/implementing-a-simple-cross-site-collection-list-view-webpart.aspx)
- Page view web part showing view page (add ?IsDlg=1 to url to get rid of chrome)